# How Can I Import java.util.Scanner into Eclipse?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I type "java.util." I don't even get the scanner option to come up on the list. I'm teaching myself java on youtube, and the guy had the option popped up for him. I can't even create a scanner since i'll get an error wtihout importing that java scanner. I can't do java.util.*; either since Eclipse doesn't recognize it as well.

Sorry, I'm still new to all of this. Do I need to manual download the java library packages or something?
What am I suppose to do?

Comment: What happens when you type out the import manually?

Comment: In your code type `Scanner` and press ctrl+space. See if it gives you options

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse should already have JDK/JRE/SDK libraries loaded. If it is showing an error when trying to import, the most likely culprit is that you are putting it in the wrong place.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // It should be above the class
public class ClassName{

}
```

I have had a lot of issues with Eclipse in the past(specifically with suggestions popping up). If you are learning I would highly recommend [BlueJ](https://www.bluej.org/) for just getting started. And then moving into [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) short there after.

Comment: I made sure to put it outside the class. I made sure to follow the setup instruction from the video and everything seems to work. It's just the scanner thing that i'm having a problem.

I'll check out those links too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are typing in a class, when you create a new project in Eclipse it's created a module-info.java.
To confirm right button in your src -> New -> Class.
Now you can type the Scanner.

You can import or use directly in declaration like you're trying:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class yourClass{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
    //or
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
}
```

Comment: Yes, when I created a new project I made sure not to create a module since it asked me. 
I went about to creating a new class in my src folder, but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EgBLl9b

Comment: Sorry, can't help buddy, I almost didn't use Eclipse, but I recommend go for IntelliJ, best IDE for java 4ever

Comment: Thank you. I might just switch over IntelliJ then if I can't find a solution

Comment: @JohnYoo you should provide this information in the question, instead of a comment below an answer. According to the screenshot you have at least two fundamental errors: 1) the class name doesn’t match the file name. Do either, name your class `ScannerTut`, to match the file name or rename the file to `yourClass.java` to match the class name. I recommend the former. 2) You have two variables of the same name (`scanner`). Declare only one variable or change the name of the second. 3) `new Scanner()` doesn’t work as there is no default constructor. You have to provide a data source argument.